# Concatenate arrays Matrix along specified dimension. Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

HOW TO concate C1 and C2 by different dimension?

```
C1 =[[0,0,1,0],
    [2,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0]]

C2=[[0,3,4,0,1,1],
    [0,0,0,5,1,1],
    [6,7,0,8,1,1]]
```

how to get the following result:

```
[[0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0, 3, 4, 0,1,1]
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,5,1,1]
 [0, 0, 0 ,0 ,6 ,7, 0, 8,1,1]]
```

and

```
[[0,0,1,0],
 [2,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,3,4,0,1,1],
 [0,0,0,5,1,1],
 [6,7,0,8,1,1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> [r1+r2 for (r1, r2) in zip(C1, C2)]
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 8, 1, 1]]

>>> C1 + C2
[[0, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1], [6, 7, 0, 8, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: My solution still works ;) I'll update value printed

Answer (score 0):

Using List Comprehensions -

```
>>> [i[0]+i[1] for i in zip(C1, C2)]
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 8, 1, 1]]

>>> C1 + C2
[[0, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1], [6, 7, 0, 8, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: if the size of C1 and C2 is different , the method cannot work

Comment: @dd90p - Modified answer.